# Why can't I compile my React-native apps anymore?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos, crash

I'm gonna ask your guidance/help for a problem I've been encountering for several days now,

I can create a new react native project (via npx react-native init projectName), but when I try to run it, either with npx react-native run-ios or yarn ios, I get the following error message:

> The following build commands failed:  CompileC
> /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Trickster-ejsutjhruuvmqjedsaarumhaquan/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o
> /Users/user/Dev/Mobile/React
> Native/Trickster/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp
> normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in
> target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

I've already cleaned yarn/npm cache, cleaned Xcode's DerivedData folder, even uninstalled node and react native from my computer, so I'm kinda lost tbh.

Here are my specs:
MacBook Pro Mid 2014 with a 2.6GHz Core i5, 8Gbs of ram running macOS Monterey 12.2.1
npm version 8.5.2, 1.22.17 and Xcode 13.2.1.

Sorry in advance if I don't answer fast, I'm a bit ill atm so kinda occupying my time till I'm better

Answer (score 1):

Try running Project from Xcode that will show you where problem exactly is

Comment: It seems the problem lies here /ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h, at this line: typedef uint8_t clockid_t; Xcode gives me the following error message:

Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')

Comment: Try this solution: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/834#issuecomment-608147914

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be for several reasons. To avoid going into so much explanation If the application worked at some point

1. Delete the app in the device and
   run `yarn android` or `npm android`
   or
2. delete the build folder and delete the app in the device and
   run `yarn android` or `npm android` or
3. on Android delete and reinstall the device then
   run `yarn android` or `npm android`

That's works for me

Comment: The problem is that my problem even happens when creating a new app